# How to identify the name of the branch when receiving a push from local repository?

Tags: git, version-control, githooks

I want to identify the name of the branch with the incoming push each time it is received from local repo. I am planning to use the branch name in a update hook. 
Pls let me know how to deal with this.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Make sure you accept answers if they solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The branch name is the first argument in the pre-update hook. The second is the old revision and the third is the new revision. Those last 2 arguments give you the range of the graph being pushed.